# There is a quick and/or accurate way to kill a crystal lizard in Demon's Souls?

Tags: demons-souls

After the fifth lizard I missed to kill, I was wondering: there is a weapon which is the best to do this? All blade weapons don't hurt it because is too short and don't hit it. The crossbow is difficult to aim in close quarters. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably mention your build, so we know which skills you have a your disposal. As I recall, [God’s Wrath](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/god-s-wrath), maybe [Firestorm](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/firestorm), are quite effective, but you may not have those spells.

The unofficial wiki has a [slew of tips](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/crystal-lizards) for you.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using a few methods:

- [Fire Spray](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/fire-spray)
- Sword (usually my Crescent Falchion)
- Arrows

But since obtaining the [**Firestorm**](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/firestorm) spell I've been using that with much more success (though still not a perfect record).

Which method I use depends on the circumstances though:

- I use **Fire Spray** if the crystal lizard is alone and I can afford to chase it (ie. it won't suicide off a cliff to escape you, or it can't get there in time).
- I've used a **sword** for lizards I can corner. Sometimes they are too low to hit though and get away anyway. (**Firestorm** works better in these circumstances - run the lizard into a corner and then blast him with the spell.)
- I use arrows on lizards I don't want to or can't chase. It helps if you have a decent bow so you can kill it with less arrows. (I'm using a **Sticky Compound Short Bow +5**.) Use the zoom feature to shoot further and more accurately. (Don't use the crossbow - it does not have the zoom feature!)

If you don't have the necessary equipment to easily and quickly kill crystal lizards, I recommend avoiding them until you do. Some lizards are not easily avoided, but many are. Don't try killing them with sub-standard equipment - their drops are too valuable to gamble with.

I'd also recommend manipulating the world into [Pure Black World Tendency](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/world-tendency) before finally killing the lizards, to give you a better chance of rare drops.

**EDIT:** One more handy tip I can give you:

Crystal lizards have a spawn count, which is well described [here](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/crystal-lizards).

If you have just hunted a lizard (successful or not), you can force a respawn of the lizard by reloading your game (using `Load Game` from the menu). If the lizard's spawn count has not already reached zero, the lizard will respawn, but the other enemies will not. Use this feature to position yourself and farm the lizards until they no longer appear.

Be aware though that in the final area of a level (where you fight the archdemon), your load position will be at the archstone, not at your previous position.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a solid hit, it will usually flip on it's back. You can usually wait until it's just flipping back over and hit it again.